# How to SELECT Comma Separated variable From Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, mysql-5.5

I Have a MySql Database Structure and values samples as shown below:

```
sno     firstname      status
1        John            Active
2        Kelly           Inactive
3        Harri           Passive
4        Kris            Dormant
```

Now that I need to execute a Sql query from a PHP page, and the Status Values are from multiple checkbox which I have assigned as an array.

I have used Implode function for this array:

```
$status = $_POST['status'];    
$mstat= implode (',', $status);
$query="SELECT * FROM USER WHERE status IN '$mstat'";
$result=mysql_query($query);

while ($members = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
        { 
        $fname= $members['firstname'];
        echo $fname;
        echo '</br>';
        }
```

The problem is that I'm not getting any results. What could be the problem. Or If anyone could suggest/Advice for an alternative.

When I `echo $mstat;` I get `Active,Passive,Dormant` (That is based on my checkbox selection)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`status` are strings. You need to wrap them with `quotes`. And `IN` needs `()` to wrap the string values. Try -

```
$mstat= "'" . implode ("','", $status) . "'";
$query="SELECT * FROM USER WHERE status IN ($mstat)";
```

Assuming `$status` contains some or all of those values showed in database in array format.

Comment: Thank You @Sougata. It Works.

Comment: Great!! Glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

Here is 100% working answer

```
$mstat= implode ("','", $status);
$query="SELECT * FROM USER WHERE status IN ('$mstat')";
```

IN works like this IN ('Active','Passive','Dormat')
so we have to add '' in all values which is done in implode function.

Comment: Thank You for the advise

Answer (score -2):

Change this line to:

```
$query="SELECT * FROM USER WHERE status IN ('$mstat')";
```

The Argument must in ()

!!!
EACH word must in ' '
like:
$query="SELECT * FROM USER WHERE status IN ('Active','Inactive')"

You can change it like:

```
if ($mstat) $query .= ' ({$db->quote($status}) ';
```

Comment: Thanks but didn't Work!!

Comment: test the query like: $query="SELECT * FROM USER WHERE status IN (1,3,5)"; or other valid values;

Comment: $query="SELECT * FROM USER WHERE status IN (Active,Inactive)"; won't work. `status` is string.

Comment: ahh, i see : each arg must in ' : $query="SELECT * FROM USER WHERE status IN (Active,Inactive)". i have change my answer

Comment: @Bernd Buffen. $mstat is the values from checkbox separated by comma. Ex: Active, Passive, Dormant. This values are not numeric. I think the IN CLAUSE works with numbers. But not working with words. That's my experience. I don't know if it's true.

Comment: @keyem `string`s need to be wrapped in quotes. You can do it when imploding.

Comment: see answer from me